# Visual Studio 2012 Update 3 - Typescript not working

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installation, typescript

1. I am using Visual Studio 2012 Professional with Update 3.
2. I have installed Typescript from [TypeScript for Visual Studio 2012 and 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34790)
   .
3. It is possible for me to add a new typescript file using "Add > New Item...".

#### But neither the editor shows the split screen (with the javascript preview) nor the `.js` file gets generated if i save the `.ts` file or build the project.

On my machine at work i have done the excactly same things withouth any problem and it works.

Please help!

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the default functionality with the latest plugin combination. See [TypeScript not compiling with WE3 and TS 0.9.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445976/typescript-not-compiling-with-we3-and-ts-0-9-1-1/18446838#18446838)

Comment: Now the .js file gets generated, the min.js file not and the split screen is not showing. Still dont know why it works on my machine at work.

Comment: You probably have an older version of WebEssentials installed on your machine at work. If you update WebEssentials, you lose the split sreen and automatic minification.

Comment: i have installed web essentials 2.9 and now everything works!